# Semantic button markup

Tags: html, semantic-markup

curious how the below might be marked up via HTML. Not sure if it's a list, if it should be separate divs (with spans maybe?) or navigation(html 5).

The button on far left is stand-alone. Then the title in center. Then a button group (back/next). Then a button (notifications) on far right.

All the buttons and title refer and act upon the content below it.

```
button         Title of page below      button(back) button(next)       button
```

Comment: The question does not anything about the meanings of the buttons or their interrelations, yet asks for “semantic markup”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's navigation and you want it to be semantic, you should wrap it in a `nav` tag. The `Nav` tag is HTML5 only, but semantically describes navigation. I would structure it like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
        <li><h1>Title</h1></li>
        <li><a href="#">Back</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Button</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It's good practice to use anchor tags for navigation and style them to look like appropriate. You should use a `<h1>` for a title, as it should be the most important heading.